# Highcharts solidgauge legend symbol not taking series color

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using `Highcharts solidgauge`, and I would like to have a legend with legend symbol, however legend symbol is not taking color from series, instead it is taking `#CCC` as some default color. Below is code snippet

```
series: [{
        showInLegend: true,
        name: 'Your Humidity Level',
        borderColor: '#00AF33',    //gives color to individual ring on graph
        color: '#00AF33',       
        data: [{          
            radius: '93%',
            innerRadius: '91%',
            y: 32,
            color: '#00AF33'
        }],
    }, {
        showInLegend: true,
        name: 'Ideal Humidity Range',
        borderColor: '#00B2EE',
        color: '#00B2EE',
        data: [{           
            radius: '83%',
            innerRadius: '82%',
            y: 50,
            color: '#00B2EE'
        }],
```

Comment: You can manipulate on SVG elements and apply right color. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2ooLgk84/

Comment: @SebastianBochan Doesn't seem to work. The second legend icon remains grey and both icons become grey after being clicked on once.

Comment: Hi @Jerry, I have added an answer with a solution that should work in your case.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that series in `solid-gauge` chart have no internal color property. As a solution, in `'afterColorizeItem'` event you can change the symbol fill color to the one set by user:

```
(function(H) {
    H.addEvent(H.Legend, 'afterColorizeItem', function(e) {
        if (e.visible) {
            e.item.legendSymbol.attr({
                fill: e.item.userOptions.color
            })
        }
    });
})(Highcharts);
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gpdsq065/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts

Comment: Looks much better :). I'll have to read and understand it thoroughly since I'm not working with jQuery or JS, but with angular and TS. It's not urgent, but something that will definitely have to be done. You don't happen to know how to implement it in typescript by any chance? ^^;

Comment: Hi @Jerry, That is only a small plugin which you should put before creating a chart. I recommend you to use official `highcharts-angular` wrapper. Docs: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#to-load-a-wrapper

Comment: Will check it out. Thank you :)

Comment: This is terrible, I love it!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can provide a static color to the gauge , but you can try giving the min and max color same to achieve that :

```
yAxis: {
...............
        minColor: 'blue',
        maxColor: 'blue',
...............
}
```